# Differenza tra "verdura" e "ortaggio"

Tags: difference, synonym

Is there any difference *in meaning* between "verdura" and "ortaggio" ?

Regarding their number inflexion, if I got it right, "verdura" is used in the singular even when it means the plural, "ortaggio" not. Is that right?

Examples:

- La patata è la verdura/l'ortaggio più popolare in Perù.
- Lui ha un negozio di frutta e verdura/ortaggi.
- I giovani non mangiano verdura / ortaggi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [blog post](https://medicinaonline.co/2018/02/22/differenza-tra-verdura-ed-ortaggi-con-esempi/) you can read about the difference between *ortaggio* and *verdura*:

> Differenza tra ortaggio e verdura
>
> Verdura ed ortaggi sono la stessa cosa? La parola “ortaggio” si
>   riferisce a tutti i prodotti vegetali coltivati nell’orto (sia a
>   livello domestico-artigianale che industriale), mentre invece la
>   parola “verdura” è un termine gastronomico che indica le parti del
>   vegetale utilizzate nell’alimentazione umana, vegetale che può essere
>   presenti allo stato selvatico o derivare da coltivazioni.
>   Semplificando: l’ortaggio è il vegetale, mentre la verdura è la parte
>   dell’ortaggio che viene mangiato. I termini in alcuni casi possono
>   essere usati come sinonimi, mentre in altri no a seconda del vegetale.

So, according to this article, the word *ortaggio* refers to all the products obtained from a vegetable garden whereas *verdura* refers to the part of the ortaggio you eat. The terms are usually used as synonyms, but sometimes it depends on the type of vegetable.

However, reading from the *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* for [verdura](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI21/GDLI_21_ocr_778.pdf&parola=):

> 3. Insieme o determinata quantità, porzione di ve­getali commestibili, di ortaggi. - Anche in un contesto figur.

and for *[ortaggio](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI12/GDLI_12_ocr_168.pdf&parola=)* you can read:

> Ortàggio,  sm.   Qualsiasi tipo di pianta che si coltiva negli orti per alimentazione o condimento (e anche la parte commestibile o i frutti di tali piante, posti in vendita o usati in cucina).

Finally, considering everyday use, it can be said that the two terms can be considered synonyms.

About the number inflexion, although being a collective noun, "verdura" is also used in its plural form, *verdure*.
Using your examples, you can say:

> - La patata è la verdura più popolare in Perù.
> - La patata è l'ortaggio più popolare in Perù.
> - Lui ha un negozio di frutta e verdura. ("verdure" would not be usual here)
> - Lui ha un negozio di frutta e ortaggi.

For the last phrase, you would have more choices:

> - I giovani non mangiano verdura.
> - I giovani non mangiano *verdure*.
> - I giovani non mangiano ortaggi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please answer the 2nd part of the question, about singular/plural usage?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Added some info.